# Is there IDE for Java like Thonny for Python? Which Shows step by step code Execution

Tags: java, python, windows, intellij-idea

Is there any IDE out there which shows step by step execution of Java code like Python has an IDE named Thonny .I may be wrong here if it is even possible because of the difference in languages such as Interpreted and Compiled .I am new to programming and I was watching the tutorials so the instructor used the Thonny IDE to explain the code the same way would be helpful if any IDE or any program can help show the working of Java code Step by Step. Also using IntelliJ Idea for Java can it be done it that just in case......?

Comment: Yes I am not looking for Java IDE instead one which can show the running of code Step by step which will help in learning

Comment: @Alfred Eclipse will do that for you in debug mode.

Comment: Questions asking for external references are explicitly off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Alfred, many beginners like BlueJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is 
You could use `Intellij IDEA Community Edition` , it's free and..
have the tool that you want.
[image: debugging area]

Click the `bug` and it will be the same like python one
[image: Step into]

[image: step over]

[image: Force Step Into]

[image: step out]

[image: variable Section]

Same as python

But make sure you have the `breakpoint`